# Finding Magnetic Flux

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic, electrical

I'm hoping someone can verify an answer I have found for the following problem:

A helmholtz coil consists of two identical circular wire loops placed coaxially. If each loop has radius a and carries current I, and the loops are seperated by distance h, find B at a point on the axis halfway between the loops.

The solution I have obtained is as follows:

[image]

Comment: which part is hard I or B or result in B/I?

Comment: There are plenty of answers on this site that tell you flux density at a certain distance from a single loop. Find one, check with another and if correct then the answer to your question is double their answer. There are several websites that will confirm this. From memory your answer looks close to being right, certainly at a great distance h dominates the answer to the power 3.

Comment: Where does the theta value come from?

Answer (score 0):

For a single coil the picture below is worth considering: -

[image]

[Picture source](http://www.thepocketlab.com/support/lesson/magnetic-field-axis-current-loop).

It has all the key elements of your derivation but there are some discrepancies. For instance, what is \$\theta\$ representing in your formula? Anyway I'm sure you can use this to develop your formula for parallel [Helmholzt coils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_coil).